# Antlr finding single characters with ' around them

Tags: antlr, grammar

I'm trying to create an ANTLR grammar with a type that has one character inside of a set of '', such as 'a', 'b', '\n'.  Since ANTLR uses the ' symbol to show what's supposed to be in that type, I don't understand how to include the ' symbol as part of my grammar.

Currently I have `CHAR: '''.''';`, but that causes errors when building the makefile (string literal and sets cannot be empty: '')

Can someone please explain how to include the ' symbol properly?

Answer (score 0):

Escape the quote with a backslash:

```
CHAR: '\'' . '\'';
```

Or use a character class:

```
CHAR: ['] . ['];
```